# Segmentation fault on XQueryTree

Tags: c++, window, x11, xlib

I'm trying to close the last used window (the one right under the current window in the stacking order). Unfortunately XQueryTree segfaults for some reason.

```
#pragma once

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

namespace WindowingOperations {

    inline void closeLastWindow() {
        Display* dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);
        Window root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);

        Window* root_return;
        Window* parent_return;
        Window** children_return;
        unsigned int* nchildren_return;

        XQueryTree(dpy,
                   root,
                   root_return,
                   parent_return,
                   children_return,
                   nchildren_return);

        // Kill the window right after this one
        if (*nchildren_return > 1)
            XDestroyWindow(dpy, *children_return[*nchildren_return - 2]);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

If you need a test case:

```
#include "window_operations.h"
int main() {
    WindowingOperations::closeLastWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I mean, this is fairly concise. It's also trivial to check whether it works or not -- just call `closeLastWindow()`

Comment: Nope! It's your turn to provide the test case. No just letting me reproduce  it somehow. Did you run that code in the debugger already?

Comment: Okay provided a test case (I don't know why you needed one given how simple it is). Yes, I ran the code in a debugger -- I get `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7017f44 in XQueryTree () from /usr/lib/libX11.so.6`

Comment: You do need to pass the address in for some of the parameters, but I already do that. See [the docs](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryTree.html). `root` is supposed to be of the type `Window` not a pointer to `Window`

Comment: @DavidThomas has the right idea, but the wrong variable. I think you want to  `Window root_return; Window parent_return; Window* children_return;         unsigned int nchildren_return;` and then `XQueryTree(dpy, root, &root_return, &parent_return, &children_return, &nchildren_return);` And don't forget to test the return value so you know that the call succeeded.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you! That was exactly it -- by passing in the address of the Window object, xlib can set the right fields in that object. Earlier I was basically passing in null pointers, which were causing the segfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_return` parameters need somewhere to go. You can't just pass in uninitialized pointers, storage needs to be allocated for `XQueryTree` to write the results in.

So...

```
namespace WindowingOperations {

    inline void closeLastWindow() {
        Display* dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);
        Window root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);

    // Allocate storage for the results of XQueryTree. 
        Window root_return;
        Window parent_return;
        Window* children_return;
        unsigned int nchildren_return;

    // then make the call providing the addresses of the out parameters
        if (XQueryTree(dpy,
                       root,
                       &root_return,
                       &parent_return,
                       &children_return,
                       &nchildren_return) != 0)
        { // added if to test for a failed call. results are unchanged if call failed, 
          // so don't use them

            // Kill the window right after this one
            if (*nchildren_return > 1)
                XDestroyWindow(dpy, *children_return[*nchildren_return - 2]);
        }
        else
        {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```